# Ubuntu 18.04 vnc grey screen on remote display

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have seen several questions about how to solve this problem. However none of the exmaples have worked for me.

I followed the install as per the link:
https://linuxconfig.org/vnc-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

then tried many different flavors of xstartup.

If someone can provide guidance on the contents of this file that works connecting from a remote Windows 10 computer, that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Malcolm